# Make child div as long as parent div

Tags: css, html

How do I make the .box div stretch to be as tall as the tallest box div?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">La</div>
    <div class="box">Lalala<BR>lala</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit<BR>amet</div>
    <div class="box">la</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { 
}
.box { 
    float: left; 
    background-color: red; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8QbGk/1

Comment: the lazy solution is to set a min-height or height on .box...

Comment: Your container has no height. Are you asking how to create columns of equal height?

Comment: I know I can do "height: XXpx". But what I want to do is make the box divs dynamically stretch to match the height of the tallest box div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `float:left` to `display:table-cell`.

```
.box { 
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2958/)

Comment: It looks like this one works! I haven't seen display:table-cell much; is it considered a best practice to use it? Edit: I just applied the display:table-cell to my website and it didn't work. http://csidb.com/stage/ Please refer to the green divs called "banner"

Comment: It treats your element as table cell. I don't think that is good practice.

Comment: @BwithLove, it displays the element like a table cell.

Comment: That is what my comment means.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height and the width to 100% like:

.container {
  height: auto;
  /*Others properties*/
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*Others properties*/
}

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100%;
```

Add that to your box style.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
.container {
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  float: left; 
  background-color: red; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following style for your child element. It will take parent element height.

```
height: inherit;
```

[See:](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/7tcva/)

Comment: I think the point of this was to accomplish it with out a fixed height.

Comment: The property itself says, Inherit. It just takes parent element height as I mentioned, whether it is fixed or non fixed.

Comment: remove the height and width of your container and you'll see it doesn't work. That's what I'm saying, you got it to work because you used a fixed pixel amount for height. Clearly this problem would be solved instantly if a fixed height were allowed. It's supposed to be dynamic